# Django VirtualEnv not properly working

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv

I'm facing a weird behavior on `Django` + `virtualenv`.

I'm working on Ubuntu x64 13.04 raring ringtail Server.

Let's say i have two projects, one developed in django 1.3 and the other on django 1.4

And in the system i have django 1.6 installed.

I follow these steps to create my virtualenv:

```
mkdir enviroments 

cd enviroments 

virtualenv --no-site-packages django1.3 

cd django1.3 

source bin/activate 

sudo pip install Django==1.3
```

Everything is ok, but when i repeat this process, but changing, let's say `Django1.3` for `Django1.4`, it just reinstalls django in root files of the pc.

I mean, it doesn't just installs django for THAT virtualenv, it reinstalls it completely in the pc, substituting the django 1.3 previously installed on the other virtualenv.

And yes, i do activate the `virtualenv` before installing Django version.

I know virtualenv exists to create and install different projects on different versions of django, on the same machine.

What could be causing this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `pip install` without `sudo`:

```
pip install Django==1.3
```